# Как сделать увеличивающееся при введении символов место для ввода

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я хотел-бы узнать, как сделать увеличивающееся поле для ввода, вместо появляющегося скролла справа сбоку. Например на CSS HTML JS
На примере вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, самое простое решение - редактируемый `div`:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("inputArea")[0].innerHTML = "";
```

```css
.inputArea:empty::before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #888;
}

.inputArea {
    word-break: break-word;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #eee;
    outline: 0px #fff solid;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="inputArea" placeholder="Введите текст">
</div>
```

При проверке оказалось, что нужна небольшая "инициализация" этого поля ввода, поэтому добавил строчку на js.

Comment: ваш пример не работает

Comment: @MaximLensky очень даже работает, попробуйте выполнить код на этой странице нажав на кнопку "Выполнить код".

Comment: https://ibb.co/tpqB00r  смотрите

Comment: @MaximLensky [работает](https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2021/02/d73e63ef18d2b8a7289caa0128cdb6ca.png)

Comment: файерфокс - решения должны быть кроссбраузерные

Comment: @MaximLensky
Спасибо за пояснение. Судя по Вашему скрину, ошибка возникает из-за того, что ширина поля не соответствует родительскому блоку. Исправил, проверьте, пожалуйста :)

Comment: тоже самое : https://ibb.co/gwMmXPr

Comment: @MaximLensky
Хорошо. Действительно, ширина не всегда должна быть равна ширине родителя. Но действительно ломает это поле свойство `word-break`. Спасибо за помощь в разработке кросс-браузерного решения

Comment: плюс поставил - работает теперь

Answer (score 2):

[Вот пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/aaroniker/pen/KKdvGGM)

> `document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(el => { el.style.height = el.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + el.scrollHeight + 'px'); el.classList.add('auto'); el.addEventListener('input', e => { el.style.height = 'auto'; el.style.height = (el.scrollHeight) + 'px'; });});`

Comment: Хороший вариант, но я забыл добавить в пост что мне нужно именно на чистом HTML CSS или JS

Comment: Тут на чистом html js, в scss думаю не сложно пару элементов поменять.